# How to correctly use in for string list in KQL

Tags: kql

the following code works

```
let names = dynamic(['Windows Installer', 'Software Protection']);

ConfigurationChange
| where Computer like "SRV"
| where SvcPreviousState  == "Running"
| where SvcState == "Stopped"
// | where SvcDisplayName in (names)
| order by TimeGenerated
```

as commented out I would like to only check for a list of SvcDisplayName's.

According to the documentation this should work but does complain

```
: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'names'
```

How would I correctly use in with a list for SvcDisplayName  ?

Comment: Remove the blank line between the `let` statement and the rest of the code :-)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz that did actually work :-o  thanks for that ! worked before with let but never had the issue though

Comment: Another option is to select the whole code and then execute it, however if you have just put the cursor on the query , the `let` statement won't be marked since it is separated with a blank line. Give me one minute to post an answer with screenshots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blank line is considered separator between queries, unless you select the whole code for execution.
See screenshots below.

**Select the whole code for execution.

=> Valid query**

[image: select the code for execution]

**Put the cursor on the query for execution.

There is no blank line after the `let` statement.

=> Valid query**

[image: put the cursor on the query for execution - without blank line]

**Put the cursor on the query for execution.

There is a blank line after the `let` statement.

=> Invalid query**

Please note how the query is marked by a pale blue color, but not the `let` statement

[image: put the cursor on the query for execution - with blank line]